# Plot histograms over factor variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to replicate the graph similar to the following (originally found [HERE](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3019-the-rhythms-of-37signals))
[image: stacked histograms]

It's conceptually simple, but I'm a bit stumped as to how to do it in R. 
To summarize: I want to generate histograms of behavioral frequency over the 24 hours of the day (24-level factor variable) by each day of the week. Then, I want to stack these histograms on top of each other so that the distribution of behavior over the hour of day can easily be compared (again, see example).

For example, my data might look like this:

```
  weekday hour    count
  Tuesday   15      553
   Monday    1       53
   Monday   10      539
   Monday   15      629
  Tuesday    9      281
 Saturday    4       11
   Monday    3       20
   Sunday    3       10
   Sunday    7        2
   Sunday    2       17
```

How do I go about implementing the graph in the link above? I'm terrible with `ggplot`, but have a sense it's the likely solution.
Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Something like this?

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(weekday=rep(sort(unique(weekdays(.leap.seconds))), each=24), 
                       hour=rep(1:24, 7), count=sample(2:600, 24*7, replace=T))

df$weekday <- factor(df$weekday, levels=c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
                      "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"), ordered=T)
df$hour <- factor(df$hour)

require(ggplot2)    
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x=hour)) 
p <- p + geom_histogram(aes(weights=count, fill=weekday))
p <- p + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set3")
p <- p + facet_wrap( ~ weekday, ncol=1)
p
```

[image: ggplot2_facet_histogram]

Comment: Nailed it. @Arun, you're the best.

Comment: Quick question. When I actually do this with my data, I am getting some gaps in the X-axis.  I'm adding the image above.

Comment: No, there are 24 different bars. I think the problem is that binwidths is being set to 30....But I don't know where to put that snippet!

Comment: @roody make sure your hour column is a factor

Comment: Yep! That was the problem. Thanks @shujaa!

Comment: @roody Sure thing. You could also probably leave it as a numeric and add `binwidths = 1` inside the `geom_histogram()` call, but as a factor the bars will be nicely centered above the label as in Arun's answer.

Comment: @Arun -- I added a quick addendum.  I'm struggling with making these different charts with separate data frames and then putting them side by side. Thoughts?

Comment: What I was doing is creating identical graphs for different behavioral variables in different data frames. There was a typo in my code which was the problem. I think I've got an ok handle on how to arrange the graphs using gridExtra. As always, thank you!!