# Plot a histogram in ggplot2

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2

want to replicate that here with my data

[Plot histograms over factor variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818529/plot-histograms-over-factor-variables)

my data look like that

```
2 -11.0  0
2 -10.8  0
2 -10.6  0
2 -10.4  0
2 -10.2  0
```

the full data frame is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/r616tyr17q40x6g/t4.RData?dl=0

the first column is the histogram number, the next is the bins an d the last is the counts per vi bin. As in the original example (weekday,hours,count).

I also factor the columns - as i dont have strings I just do

```
as.factor(df[,3])-.df[,3]
asfactor(df[,2])->df[,2]
```

The bins are the same for every histogram. Histogram 1 to 1598 all have 60 bins which range from -11 to plus 2 by 0.2. This is in col 2. The specific count is in col 3 and the ind is in col 1.

I then do

```
p<-ggplot(data=t4, aes(x=V2))
p<-p+geom_histogram(aes(weights=V3))
p<-p+facet_wrap(~V1,ncol=1)
```

when i plot p i get

```
Error in Summary.factor(structure(1L, .Label = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4",  : 
  sum not meaningful for factors
```

for every histogram.

Why do I get that error>

how owuld I also get rid of the large header for every histogram plotted in the code - in my case it would look like that 
http://postimg.org/image/4yhvz9i67/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, your `V2` and `V3` columns are factors. Just run

```
t4$V2 <- as.numeric(t4$V2)
t4$V3 <- as.numeric(t4$V3)
```

And this problem will be solved. It's a good idea to figure out why they were factors in first place, maybe you'll have to adjust your function to read the data into R.

I don't think you want to to use the facets this way though. It will try to create 1599 facets which for me froze the R session before it actually plotted.

After that I got the following plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=t4, aes(x=V2)) + geom_histogram(aes(weights=V3))
```

[image]

Comment: the problem is that if it is numeric it will not work - according to the original post and you have to specify the abndwith parameter that is ther error Igt...do you have an idea how to plot 1600 vertically?

Comment: if i do it numeri cthan i get exactly what i show as a picture..there has to be soem other way.....

Comment: @heineman Check my edit. I got a regular histogram, not what you posted as an image. Is that what you're looking for? The factors used in the linked answer aren't the counted elements, but the groups. I think you should read that again.

Comment: the plot should be 1600 hists below each other nto only 1 and the bin are messed up because it is no longer a facto

Comment: If you want to plot 1600 histograms one above the other, something just isn't right. You'll either need a very very large image or you won't be able to see anything on it.

Comment: how do you get these groups then ...do i have to use soemthign different than the command i used to get factors? the input format in the answer is the same as in my case..

Comment: if i just take col 1 aqnd 2 as factor and then let the other be numeric i get the same error wehn i do the plotting....Error in Summary.factor(structure(1L, .Label = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4",  : 
  sum not meaningful for factors
Error in exists(name, envir = env, mode = mode) : 
  argument "env" is missing, with no default

Comment: have you tried it yourself..because i dont think it work